# Multiple dropmenu buttons - Open only clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery, unique

I found good split dropmenu button script.

Created multiple buttons, and problem is if I click one button then all dropmenus of other buttons open...

So what I want to accomplish is only to open dropmenu that i've clicked not all menus (10post per page so i have 10buttons) that are on page.

Guess I need some id recognition code in my .js.

my script:

```js
  $(function() {
  var splitBtn = $(".x-split-button");
  $("button.x-button-drop").on("click", function() {
    if (!splitBtn.hasClass("open"))
      splitBtn.addClass("open");
  });

  $(".x-split-button").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $("html").on("click", function() {
    if (splitBtn.hasClass("open"))
      splitBtn.removeClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
.x-split-button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.x-button {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 27px;
  background: #F2F2F2;
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #E0E0E0;
}

.x-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #E0E0E0;
}

.x-button:active {
  background: #D3D3D3;
}

.x-button.x-button-drop {
  border-left: 0;
  height: 30px;
}

.open > .x-button-drop-menu {
  display: block;
}

.x-button-drop-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  color: #000000;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #E0E0E0;
}

.x-button-drop-menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center><font color="green">1st forum post....text goes here....</font><br/>

<span class="x-split-button">
      <button class="x-button x-button-main">Admin Options</button>
      <button class="x-button x-button-drop">&#9660;</button>
      <ul class="x-button-drop-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="">Edit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Delete</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Move</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </span>
    
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><font color="green">2nd forum post....text goes here....</font><br/>
    <span class="x-split-button">
      <button class="x-button x-button-main">Admin Options</button>
      <button class="x-button x-button-drop">&#9660;</button>
      <ul class="x-button-drop-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="">Edit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="">Delete</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Move</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </span>
    </center>
```

Comment: `$(this).hasClass("open")` <= `this` inside an event handler (not using an arrow function) will be the element that is processing the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery `$(this)` is concerned about the element concerned in this function (Onclick).  We use closest() to reach The parent container (.x-split-button) which is the targeted  element in this case.

We can also use `$(this).parent(".x-split-button").addClass("open");`

In other situations, you could use `$(this).parents();` when the container is not a direct parent.

```js
$(function() {
  var splitBtn = $(".x-split-button");
  $("button.x-button-drop").on("click", function() {
    if (!($(this).closest(".x-split-button").hasClass("open"))){
 splitBtn.removeClass("open");
  $(this).closest(".x-split-button").addClass("open");
}else{
  $(this).closest(".x-split-button").removeClass("open");
  }});

  $(".x-split-button").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $("body").on("click", function() {
    if (splitBtn.hasClass("open"))
      splitBtn.removeClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
.x-split-button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.x-button {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 27px;
  background: #F2F2F2;
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #E0E0E0;
}

.x-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #E0E0E0;
}

.x-button:active {
  background: #D3D3D3;
}

.x-button.x-button-drop {
  border-left: 0;
  height: 30px;
}

.open > .x-button-drop-menu {
  display: block;
}

.x-button-drop-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  color: #000000;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #E0E0E0;
}

.x-button-drop-menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center><font color="green">1st forum post....text goes here....</font><br/>

<span class="x-split-button">
      <button class="x-button x-button-main">Admin Options</button>
      <button class="x-button x-button-drop">&#9660;</button>
      <ul class="x-button-drop-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="">Edit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Delete</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Move</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </span>
    
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><font color="green">2nd forum post....text goes here....</font><br/>
    <span class="x-split-button">
      <button class="x-button x-button-main">Admin Options</button>
      <button class="x-button x-button-drop">&#9660;</button>
      <ul class="x-button-drop-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="">Edit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="">Delete</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Move</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </span>
    </center>
```

Comment: You are welcome :) I just added an explanation to my answer

Comment: Excellent. Good to know.

Comment: After your help I was faced with another little problem. When I click on these two dropmenus they're wont close until i click on body (tnx for that) then my idea was that when I click on 2nd button that action will close 1st button. So I added some more actions (hope I didn't do anything wrong, it works for me). I will post this updated code in case anyone needs it.   Thanks again for quick and kind help :)

Comment: Yes sure! I found html I thought it would be better using body..